# Async Nested Callbacks using Express + Request node module in a MVC structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, node-request

I'm struggling with what feels like the final step in passing some data from a model file back into a controller using Node Request.

I've successfully set up a callback from my model file which uses request to load JSON from an external source.

My controller can access this, but I think I still need some kind of nested second callback in the final step as I want the variable pageJSON to contain the JSON object and can't quite figure out how.

Think I've hit a bit of a brick wall with this and some fresh eyes on the problem would be appreciated! It feels like I'm missing something really simple at this point (I hope!)

My model file:

```
module.exports = function (config, callback) {
  const request = require('request');
  const options = {
    'url' :  config.urls.page,
    'json' : true,
    'auth': {
      'user': config.auth.username,
      'pass': config.auth.password
    }
  };

  request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    callback(body);
  });
}
```

My controller file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();
const config = require('../config');
const page = require('../models/page');

let pageJSON = page(config, (json) => {
  console.log(json); // This shows the JSON structure in console
  return json;
});

console.log(pageJSON); // Undefined

// Manipulate JSON and pass request view accordingly using Express
```

Comment: Can't you just put the rest of your code inside the callback in the controller file?

Comment: I'm not familiar with node-request but I notice that your `page` function returns nothing. So `pageJSON = page(...)` must be wrong

Comment: It looks like pageJSON is returning a value in an asynchronous way. You might need to call to another function with the returned json or pass a function to pageJSON as a callback to be called when the json is returned.

Comment: obviously the json manipulation must take place in your callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to deal with json manipulation within your controller callback (or call another callback from it):

```
let pageJSON = page(config, (json) => {
   console.log(json); // This shows the JSON structure in console
   processJSON(json);
});
```

`pageJSON` is `undefined` because nothing is returned from your model.